# gotoScene в Corona SDK отказывается работать

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Есть код, где из main.lua идет переход в menu.lua, а оттуда хочу сделать переход в scene1.lua, но при вводе правильного имени сцены симулятор дает ошибку global `sceneName` (a nil value), но как только ввожу какое-либо неправильное значение sceneName, он выдает ошибку о том, что такой сцены. Как решить такую проблему? Причем в другом проекте такой же код работал без проблем.

main.lua:

```
local composer = require("composer")
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
composer.gotoScene( "menu" )
```

menu.lua:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene("menu")
local xc = display.contentCenterX
local yc = display.contentCenterY
local width = display.contentWidth
local height = display.contentHeight

local function OnPlayButton()
  composer.gotoScene( "scene1", {time=800, effect="crossFade"} )
end
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared on screen
    local background = display.newRect( sceneGroup, xc, yc, width, height )
    background:setFillColor(61/255, 238/255, 158/255)
    local playButtonb = display.newRect(sceneGroup, xc, yc+205, 128*4, 130 )
    playButtonb:setFillColor(54/255, 161/255, 238/255)
    local playButton = display.newText(sceneGroup, "Play", xc, yc+190, native.systemFont, 128)

    playButtonb:addEventListener("tap", OnPlayButton)
end
```

scene1.lua:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared on screen
    local background = display.newRect( xc, yc, width, height )
    background:setFillColor(43/255, 237/255, 132/255)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, потому что main.lua не является сценой. В общем, сделай просто переход на сцену, которая тебе нужна. Main.lua не предназначен для этого.